# How to set webServiceURL and register successfully

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I fill some parts of `webserviceURL`, but for `deviceID`, what do I put for it? This is the code I use to register device and  pass for webservice. What do I need to change in order to register after adding pass ?

```
<?php 

    echo "<a href= 'genericPass.php'> Click here to add Generic Pass</a><br/>";
    echo "<a href= 'couponPass.php'> Click here to add Coupon Pass</a>";

    $url = 'https://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/v1/devices/{deviceID}/registrations/‌​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2';

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
?>
```

Comment: could you answer my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a pass is added to Passbook - the iPhone or iPod will call the webServiceURL to tell you it's device ID and push token.  There is no way you can know what these are, so you need to set your web server up so that it can catch both the device ID and the push token.

The Device ID is sent as part of the URL and the token is posted as a JSON object.

On your web server, you need to set a rewrite rule to write all traffic from `https://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/....` to `https://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/index.php` (search Google or SO on how to do this)

Then set up a index.php something like this:

```
// Transfer Request URL into array
$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));

/**
* Register Device
*
*   POST request to version/devices/<deviceLibraryIdentifier>/registrations/<passTypeIdentifier>/<serialNumber>
*   Request will contain an Authorisation header with the value <ApplePass authenticationToken>, where
*   authenticationToken equals the authenticationToken in the original voucher payload.
*/

if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST"
    && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
    && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 'ApplePass') === 0
    && $request[2] === "devices"
    && $request[4] === "registrations") {

    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);

    $device_id = $request[3];
    $pass_id = $request[5];
    $serial = $request[6];

    // Catch the JSON post and decode it
    $dt = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $device_token = json_decode($dt);
    $device_token = $device_token->pushToken;
    if (!$device_token) die('No Token Found'); // Token wasn't found

    // Add code to check the Auth Token against the serial number and add the
    // device details to your database so you can use them later to push updates
    // to the pass. This code should return a 200, 201 or other response depending
    // on whether the auth is valid and the device is registered already or not

    exit;
}

//  Add other conditions to check for unregister, get serials, refresh and log.
```

Comment: rewrite rule is like this: RewriteRule ^.*(html|php)$ index.php [L] ?

Comment: //or                                                              RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: You're on the right track but since you are using a sub folder (passesWebServer) you may need to modify the RewriteBase, and the final RewriteRule to refer to this folder. I haven't used Apache in a long while (we use nginx) so you're better off asking an expert.

Comment: Yes, the code above, if extended for the other methods would provide a RESTful service

Comment: if i don't have index.php in my server, so i don't need to rewrite rule, right ?

Comment: All requests going to `http://yourdomain_or_ip/passesWebserver/xxx/yyy/zzz/etc.` need to be redirected to a single file that will analyse the full URL and process the request data.  This file can be called index.php or smallgirl.php - the name doesn't matter, but you need a file to put your code in.  Your rewrite rule needs to redirect requests to this file.

Comment: could you add some example codes of adding code to check the Auth Token against the serial number and add the device details to database ?

Comment: Urrm, at this rate I'll will be building your entire project. Adding and retrieving records from a database and checking if two values match are basic programming fundamentals.

Comment: What is the result of checking Authentication Token and serial number ?

Comment: If the `authenticationToken` and the `serialNumber` match a pass record in your database, it means you can trust the `deviceTypeIdentifier` and `pushToken` and respond to future requests by that device to deliver or re-deliver a pass.  If they don't match, it could mean that someone is fraudulently trying to obtain a pass.

Comment: For example, in pass.json,  "authenticationToken" :"Fy7Iiew81JNdsdaG",do i need to install this authenticationToken in pass_table, then i can compare $auth_key to this authenticationToken and $serial to serialnumber in pass_table ?

Comment: There's no 'need' to do anything - the level of security and amount of validation that you want to do is up to you, but I would recommend that you each record in your pass_table has an field for each key in your pass.json.  Your devices_table should have the `deveiceLibraryIdentifier`, `authenticationToken`, `pushToken`, `passTypeIdentifier` and  `serialNumber`

Comment: what about registration table ? in my database, i have deviceID and pushToken in Devices table; deviceID, passTypeID, serialnmber in registration table; so i only add authenticationToken to devices table, and i don't have to add serialNumber, passTypeIdentifier to devices table ?

Comment: for another question: data that I have to have in database before a device register are authenticationToken, passTypeIdentifier, and all information of the pass ?

Comment: another one question: can I use header for redirect to index.php :  header("Location: index.php");
header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $location

Comment: For the redirect you cannot do this with a header.  If you enter `https://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/v1/devices/ad79f123448fc982355f/registrations/‌​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2` into your browser you will get a 404 error because without a rewrite rule, your browser will be looking for an index.php file in the folder `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/v1/devices/ad79f123448fc982355f/registrations/‌​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2/` which will not exist.  For the database, you need to have a common key between each of your tables - I don't think you have that.

Comment: Serial number might work for you, keep in mind that a single pass can be installed on multiple devices so you will need to handle one to many relationships in your devices and registration tables. You could always just copy the sample database structure in Apple's [Ruby sample implementation in of Passbook web service](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=passbook)

Comment: but ruby is used for this example , not php, could   you figure it out some ?

Comment: It's Ruby, not rocket science!! If you read through pass_server.rb, you can figure out the tables, field names, queries and validation logic from this well commented script.

Comment: I test index.php with your code above, but it doesn't work ! Do I have to define request_URI ?

Comment: what does `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` return?  'REQUEST' needs to be in capitals.

Comment: /passWebserver/ArrayNo Token Found

Comment: I add this link to index.php                                                          <?php 
 echo "<a href= 'couponPass.php'> Click here to add Coupon Pass</a>";
.......

Comment: //and also                                                            $dbhost = 'localhost:8889';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'root';
  $dbname = 'passesdb';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  
  or die ('Error connecting to mysql'.mysql_error());    
    
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
  mysql_query($sql,$conn);
  $table = 'Devices';
  $sql = mysql_query("insert into Devices values('$device_id','$pushtoken')");
  mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Why do you need this `<?php echo "<a href= 'couponPass.php'> Click here to add Coupon Pass</a>";`.  Only devices are going to visit this page - no human should ever see it.  That's why it's called a web SERVICE, not a web PAGE!

Comment: because i want to add a pass by link, so how can user get a pass ?

Comment: I can add a pass by go to https://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/couponPass.php ; but how to know the value of $device_id, I try by echo $device_id, but i see nothing show and I rewrite for all traffics by writing in .htaccess: Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /CI_Application/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: but it doesn't go to index.php

Comment: Sorry - but until you understand that YOUR PHONE needs to tell your WEB SERVICE it's ID and pushToken you will not get any further.  When you add the pass to your phone, YOUR PHONE will visit your WEB SERVICE.  Your web service needs to look at the URL that YOUR PHONE used and record that as the $device_id.

Comment: Your link to couponPass.php should sit on your nice pretty website.  The user clicks it, and couponPass.php serves up a .pkpass file.  The user then clicks 'Add' and then THEIR PHONE visits your WEB SERVICE using a unique URL that contains their device ID which you can never determine in advance.

Comment: I add the end of index.php, I add: $dbhost = 'localhost:8889';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'root';
  $dbname = 'passesdb';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  
  or die ('Error connecting to mysql'.mysql_error());    
    
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
  mysql_query($sql,$conn);
  $table = 'Devices';
  $sql = mysql_query("insert into Devices values('$device_id','$pushtoken')");
  mysql_query($sql);
    exit;

Comment: but nothing add to database

Comment: hook your iPhone up to you Mac and monitor the device console in Xcode as you add the pass to your device.  You should see the device trying to register with your web service and the response that it receives.

Comment: I see this : Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.PassKit failed, why ?

Comment: Open a new question, paste as much of the console output from `<Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <https:/192.168.1.105:8888/passWebserver/v1/devices/edfaf551032d5b268bbfd2d8d71e5625/registrations/​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2>` as you can

Comment: now I can rewrite rule direct to index.php, but i cannot catch REQUEST _URI, This is the code that i implement:

Comment: $pushtoken=json_decode($dt)->pushToken;
    if (!$device_token) die('No Token Found'); // Token wasn't found
     include("connectdb.php");
  $querySelect = mysql_query("select * from DigiCardPass");
  
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($querySelect)){
  
   if ($pass_id == $row['PassTypeID'] && $serial ==$row['SerialNo.'] && $auth_key == $row['AuthenticationToken']){
  
    $queryInsert= mysql_query("insert into Devices values('$device_id','$pushtoken')");
   }
  }
  
  mysql_close($con);
  
    exit;
}

Comment: if you add `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` as the first line of index.php then visit `https:/192.168.1.105:8888/passWebserver/v1/devices/edfaf551032d5b268bbfd2d8d71e‌​5625/registrations/​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2` in you browser, what do you see? (don't forget to remove `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` afterward).

Comment: I see this : SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Comment: Your Apache server doesn't have an SSL certificate installed so it cannot service the https request!! Ask a MAMP expert how to generate and install a self signed certificate.

Comment: Or it could be that you do have a certificate installed, but SSL is running on a port other than 8888.